# Android: BigDecimal always show number up to 2 decimal places

Tags: android, bigdecimal, number-formatting

```
String TotalAmount= "";
```

Lets say I have TotalAmount  = `10`, or `10.1` or `10.11` or `10.11111`

```
BigDecimal Amount = new BigDecimal(amount);
```

I want `Amount` in this pattern `#.##`

```
10 -> 10.00
10.1 -> 10.10
10.11 -> 10.11
10.11111 -> 10.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself

```
BigDecimal TotalAmount= new BigDecimal(myAmount);
BigDecimal Amount = TotalAmount.divide(new BigDecimal(1),2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try java.text.NumberFormat,

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
String res = nf.format(Amount);
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: getting error 12-26 19:57:02.357: E/AndroidRuntime(15870): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 19:57:02.357: E/AndroidRuntime(15870): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
12-26 19:57:02.357: E/AndroidRuntime(15870):  at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:313)
12-26 19:57:02.357: E/AndroidRuntime(15870):  at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:732)
12-26 19:57:02.357: E/AndroidRuntime(15870):  at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:133)

Comment: amount should be BigDecimal not String

Comment: now your code is working but problem is BigDecimal is not showing ".00" part, which makes problem unsolved

Comment: @SyedZahidAli I tried all your 4 input: 10, 10.1, 10.11, 10.111 with BigDecimal, it just return the required result. I don't get how 'BigDecimal is not showing ".00" '

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) (similar to NumberFormat but working with BigDecimal)